# Consumir método complextype web services con c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net, visual-studio-2015

mi pregunta es la siguiente, necesito consumir un web servicies en un windows from,
tengo la url del web servicies y el wsdl, ya tengo realizada la referencia en mi windows from y todo, lo que pasa es que al realizar la invocación del método hay un parámetro al cual no puedo acceder, no se si tenga que crear un objeto y enviarlo pero es el unció parámetro el cual me presenta el problema.

acá esta una parte del wsdl al cual no puedo acceder.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la forma en la que estoy haciendo el llamado al método y el error que esto provoca.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me puede colaborar con ese detalle se lo agradecería infinitamente, estoy trabajando c# con visual 2015.

Comment: Mira por favor [ask]. Nos podes mostrar el codigo donde falla esto?

Comment: Amigo, ya modifique la pregunta y añadí el error que presenta, te agradezco si me puedes colaborar con la solución.

Comment: Esta esperando un array de FormaPago, y vos solamente estas mandando un objeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que recibes se debe a que la propiedad venta.FormasPago espera un Array de ServiceReference1.FormaPago. Para solucionar este problema debes primero inicializar el array:

```
 venta.FormasPago = new ServiceReference1.FormaPago[1]; //<----Cantidad de registros que tendrá el array. Si solo vas a agregar un registro entonces el valor es uno como en el caso del ejemplo de tu código.
 venta.FormasPago[0] = formaPago;
```

Comment: Amigo muchísimas gracias, con eso solucione el problema :D